# Apply Jquery to generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I've got this code:

```
//nextButton processing
    $('.nextButton').on("click", function(){
    //$('.nextButton').click(function(){

         var querystring = $("#formStep").serialize() + "&step=" + step + "&session=" + session;
        // Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: querystring,
                url: "includes/processnext.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(msg){
                    $('.result').append(msg.answerRow);

                }
            });

  // End Ajax Call
    });
```

Now this works for the first .nextbutton on there, but the ajax result replaces it with a next next button.

To fix this i tried using the Jquery .on() (old code commented out) but that doesn't seem to have solved it either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Post a jsFiddle if you can, far easier to analyse.

Comment: You want to make use of event delegation. Read the section *Direct and delegated events* in the `.on` documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the `click` event handler to a container element, like this:

```
$('#container').on("click", ".nextButton", function(){
```

The container element will then "catch" the click event as it bubbles up from the `.nextButton`.

Answer (score 0):

you are right, `.on()` its the way, but you're lacking the last step.
you have to delegate the events to the parent.

that way, any object with that class will have the click event handled.

```
$('#parent').on('click','.nextButton',function(e){...});
```

more info --> http://api.jquery.com/live/